# How do I make UniformServer Zero start as a Service?

Tags: windows, wamp

I have Uniform Server Zero, but I would like it to start automatically.

As it is now, it starts when I log on, and shuts down when I log out. I want it to be up all the time.

Is there a proper way to achieve this? There are instructions for older versions (8.something) on the project wiki, but I haven't been able to locate any instructions for the latest, reworked, version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniform Server 11_0_7_ZeroXI.exe supports running as a service.
It requires module (plugin) ZeroXI_uniservice_1_0_1.exe

Download page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/miniserver/files/Uniform%20Server%20ZeroXI/